# ¿Cómo comparar datos entre un array y un array anidado?

Tags: javascript, array, loops

## **Hola a todos**

#### tengo el siguiente desafio, que consiste en sacar datos de un array anidado comparandolos con el array de datos validos:

```
var validValues = ["0", "1"];
var corruptData = [
   ["0", "2", "0", "E", "1", "1", "u", "0", "1", "0", ":", "1"],
   ["0", "0", "1", "9", "0", "}", "1", "l", "1", "1", "1", "˜"],
   ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"],
   ["r", "8", "c", "]", "2", "Z", "H", ";", "Á", "l", "4", "?"],
   ["Y", "0", "0", "1", "1", "K", "1", ".", "0", "v", "0", "1"]
];
```

> este es mi codigo:

```
var validData =[];
for(i=0; i <= validValues.length; i++ ){
//console.log('en el indice: ' + i + ' hay este valor: '+ validValues[i]);
for (j=0; j < corruptData.length; j++){
    //console.log(corruptData.length);
    for(k=0; k < corruptData[j].length; k++)
    console.log('en el indice: ' + j + ' en la posicion '+ k + ' hay este valor: '+ corruptData[j][k]);
    if(corruptData[j][k] === validValues[i]){
  //use push to insert element in new array
  validData.push(corruptData[j][k]);
    }
  }console.log(validData);
}
```

> pero no hace push(undefined), aunque si recorre el array, ayuda por favor

Comment: Hola Ecanro. Explica mejor cuál es la meta del objetivo y ejemplos de cmportamientos esperado. Explica como intentas resolverlo (no solo el codigo ) y mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Prueba a poner el codigo en un snippet valido (pulsa `<>` en el editor de pregutna) para que podamos probarlo. Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

En la variable resultado hay un array asociativo del número de veces que aparece cada valor del array validValues.

Edito: Otra forma de iterar, como aparece al final, es con for ... in, pero esta última no es exclusiva de los arrays en Javascript.

```js
var validValues = ["0", "1"];
var corruptData = [
   ["0", "2", "0", "E", "1", "1", "u", "0", "1", "0", ":", "1"],
   ["0", "0", "1", "9", "0", "}", "1", "l", "1", "1", "1", "˜"],
   ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"],
   ["r", "8", "c", "]", "2", "Z", "H", ";", "Á", "l", "4", "?"],
   ["Y", "0", "0", "1", "1", "K", "1", ".", "0", "v", "0", "1"]
];

var resultado = [];

validValues.forEach(function(elementoValido)
   {
  resultado[elementoValido]  = 0;
   })

corruptData.forEach(function(arrayCorrupto)
{
  arrayCorrupto.forEach(function(elementoCorrupto)
    {
      validValues.forEach(function(elementoValido)
        {
          if(elementoCorrupto == elementoValido)
           {
             resultado[elementoValido]++;
           }
        })
        
    })
})

for (var key in resultado) {
console.log(key + "->" + resultado[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es **eliminar** del array anidado `corruptData` todos los valores que no se encuentren en el array `validValues`. Para ello puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```js
var validValues = ["0", "1"];
var corruptData = [
   ["0", "2", "0", "E", "1", "1", "u", "0", "1", "0", ":", "1"],
   ["0", "0", "1", "9", "0", "}", "1", "l", "1", "1", "1", "˜"],
   ["x", ".", "d", "2", "|", "[", "z", "8", "s", "d", "2", "5"],
   ["r", "8", "c", "]", "2", "Z", "H", ";", "Á", "l", "4", "?"],
   ["Y", "0", "0", "1", "1", "K", "1", ".", "0", "v", "0", "1"]
];

for (j = 0; j < corruptData.length; j++){
   for(k = 0; k < corruptData[j].length; k++){

      if (validValues.indexOf(corruptData[j][k]) === -1){
         var i = corruptData[j].indexOf(corruptData[j][k]);
         corruptData[j].splice(i, 1);
         k--;
      }
   }
}

console.log(corruptData);
```

En el código que te muestro estamos usando principalmente las siguientes funciones:

- **indexOf**: Nos devuelve el primer índice en el que se encuentra un elemento en un array. Nos devuelve -1 en caso de no encontrarlo ([Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)).
- **splice**: Modificamos el contenido de un array indicandole el índice donde se comenzará a modificar y el número de elementos que queremos eliminar, en este caso 1 ([Documenación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)).